# How do I place this button correctly?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to place a button. I have its position set to absolute, so I can't figure out how to place it properly.

Its the button that says "Is this your product?"

See an example here: (removed)

I want it to be placed right on top of the widget in the right sidebar with 5px spacing all around. How do I do that?

I originally took the button from here: http://cssdeck.com/t/uHhhprW6

Appreciate the help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I tried using float, but it didn't help. If I remove 'position: absolute' it gets closer to what I need, but not all the way.

Comment: use position: relative and remove the top & left, float and some of that right margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way I could get it to work was remove the `top`, `left`, `float`, and `margin-left` declarations from your `.email` rule, and change its `position` to `relative`.

```
.email {
position: relative; /* not absolute */
width: 220px;
height: 30px;
font: .75em "lucida grande", arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

I would imagine there are much cleaner/simpler ways to make this particular button - there seems to be a lot of absolute positioning going on with the containing element and its children. But the changes I have suggested seem to work as a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

if your `Button` will be always in same place so you can do it with:

```
​.but {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    right: 0;
    margin: 5px;
}​
```

And just edit your `right` or `top` whatever you want. [little example](http://jsfiddle.net/L4j8K/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: absolute` on the button, you can specify it's location using the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties. For example, to position an element with the id `button` to the top right of a page, with 5px spacing both on top and at the right, you could use this CSS code:

```
#button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

If you just want the element to go to the right side of the parent element, you should use `float: right`. Then you can use `margin-top`, `margin-right`, `margin-bottom` and `margin-left` to make sure the element gets some margin around it.

See my [example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/2veqC/) for the difference. Note that both 'buttons' are within the same div in the HTML code, but the absolute positioned one appears to be outside of that block.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) for more information on CSS positioning.

Answer (score 0):

When an element has `position: absolute`, you have to position it using `left`, `right`, `top`  and `bottom`. The values you use on this properties should be relative to the closest positioned ancestor (a "positioned" element being one with a `position` value other than blank or `static`).

Consider, for example, the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="position_me"></div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#container { 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 500px; 
    position: relative; 
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#position_me { 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100px; 
    top: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The red box will be 100 px from the top border of the container, and 100px from the left border of the container.

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/K9NLw/).